# Classic ASP Error 405

Tags: asp-classic, iis-5

I have several development sites on my wix XP laptop (all classic asp). Doe anyone know why i need to type localhost/site/default.asp (i keep getting a 405 error on iis 5.1) and not just localhost/site

Answer (score 10):

You need to add "Default.asp" as a default document.  [From this page](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum23/1678.htm) ...

> With iis 4.0 and iis 5.0 the change is
>   performed as follows:
>
> 1. Start the Internet Service Manager (Start - Programs - Administrative
>      Tools - Internet Services Manager).
> 2. Expand the computer and select the web site.
> 3. Right click on it and select Properties.
> 4. Select the documents tab.
> 5. Check the Enable default document box and click Add to add a new default
>      name. The order of the search can be
>      changed by clicking the up and down
>      arrows.
> 6. Click Apply and then OK.

Per comment ... okay, check your script map settings, [per this article](http://www.somacon.com/p126.php).

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need to configure your default document type in IIS to be default.asp.

Answer (score 3):

First off we need to clear up the web site thing.  You only have one *web site*, the default web site.  (It is possible to munge the metabase on XP to create multiple web sites but IIS 5.1 will only serve one of them, the others will have to be stopped).

You have multiple *applications* which are virtual directories under a common default website.

Have you checked that Default.asp is in the list of default documents for the **application** not the website?  In IIS manager open properties dialog on each applications virtual directory and check the config there.

If you have then you've got a strange one on your hands.  At this point I would always advise checking permissions.  Does the application allow anonymous access, if so does the anonymous user have access to the folder and files?

This might seem strange advice since accessing the default.asp directly works but in my experience when the configuration looks good and should work but isn't 90% of the time its the result of permissions not correctly set up.

Answer (score 0):

A 405 http response status code means "Method Not Allowed". The Wikipedia article [List of HTTP Status Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) has this definition for the error:

> A request was made of a resource using
>   a request method not supported by that
>   resource; for example, using GET on
>   a form which requires data to be
>   presented via POST, or using PUT on a
>   read-only resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the third  XP PRO IIS Admin, which can add more than one site to the IIS 5.1, you can switch the site with no difficulty.